# Import local (on disk) KML file with Googlemaps js in web app

Tags: javascript, google-maps, import, local, kml

I am developing a web application with a Google maps JS.
The GoogleMaps API allows you to import kml files from a server.

```
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: url_kml_finale,
    map: map
});
google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'status_changed', function() {...}...
```

I would like to import a KML file from my hard drive. Is that possible? I did not find a function in the API to parse a kml file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  `google.maps.KmlLayer` elements are rendered server-side on Google's infrastructure so they need to be accessible to the internet.

One workaround - you could try to load KML just like a regular XML file and locally parse it and draw the markers, polylines, and polygons yourself.  Depending on the complexity of your KML file, this could be a bit of work.

If you can convert the data to GeoJSON (maybe using something like [togeojson](https://mapbox.github.io/togeojson/)) you could use `google.maps.Data` to add it to your map.

Comment: OK thanks for your answer. It is still a pity that google maps is not provided for this scenario! Maybe in a future version of the API.
Indeed, alternative solutions may be considered, but overall they are hard to put into practice.